# VirtualAlloc a writeable, unbacked "throw-away" garbage range?

Tags: winapi, memory-address, virtual-memory, virtual-address-space

Is it possible in **Win32** to get a writeable (or write-only) range of "garbage" virtual address space (*i.e.*, via [`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc), [`VirtualAlloc2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2), [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex), or other) that never needs to be persisted, and thus ideally is never backed by physical memory or pagefile?

This would be a "hole" in memory.

The scenario is for simulating a dry-run of a sequential memory writing operation just in order to obtain the size that it actually consumes. You would be able to use the exact same code used for actual writing, but instead pass in an un-backed "garbage" address range that essentially ignores or discards anything that's written to it. In this example, the size of the "void" address range could be 2⁶⁴ = 18.4[ᴇʙ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) (why not? it's *nothing*, after all), and all you're interested in is the final value of an advancing pointer.

**[edit:] *see comments section for the most clever answer. Namely: map a single 4K page multiple times in sequence, tiling the entire "empty" range***

Comment: `DiscardVirtualMemory` comes close, but it's used after using the memory, not preemptively.

Comment: A better approach might be to commit only a single page of RAM, but map it multiple times into your target address range.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's brilliant; hoping for a "proper" technique, the slight kludge of a 4K expense didn't occur to me. If you write it up as an answer, I'd mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. If you have code that attempts to write to memory then the virtual memory needs to be backed with something.

However, if you modified your code to use the stream pattern then you could provide a stream implementation that ignored the write and just tracked the size.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "magic ring buffer" and read this article https://ruby0x1.github.io/machinery_blog_archive/post/virtual-memory-tricks/index.html

Basically you map and remap a chunk of physical memory over and over into virtual memory at higher and higher addresses. You can do this as many times as you want. It will use a small amount of physical memory but all the rest will be 'virtual'. Magic indeed

Comment: *"into virtual memory at higher and higher addresses. You can do this as many times as you want."* - No, you cannot. Addresses cannot become arbitrarily large.

Comment: Correct. I meant within the limits of the address space but didn't mention it explicitly